# connect linux server without network devices

Tags: linux

I have a Linux server (Fedora) and a Windows machine. I need to connect these machines using peer to peer method (without using any switches or routers) and give that static IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is just a crossover cable.

http://www.networking.windowsreinstall.com/directconnectionnetwork/index.htm

Comment: Unless both machines are really old, at least one of the network cards probably supports [Auto-MDIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_dependent_interface#Auto-MDIX), in which case any old Ethernet cable will do.

Comment: @Patches, yes, so normal cable is enough for most cases.

Answer (score -2):

What about this
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-configure-ubuntu-fedora-linux-pptp-client.html

Comment: Could you summarize the article please? We prefer you dont just link to things.